# Xpath select parent element using inner text

Tags: xpath, webdriver

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected">
Select this box
</input>
</div>
```

Hi I am attempting to select the checkbox using the innertext within the xpath however no luck so far.
For example I know the following does not work: //input[contains(text(), ' Select this box')]

Any suggestions as to the correct syntax please? Note, it needs to include the innertext.

Thanks

Comment: Typical. Answer found just by additional experimenting with xpath: //div[text() = ' Select this project']//input

Comment: So you were trying to find text '_Select this box_', but the text was actually '_Select this project_'? No wonder your xpath didn't work at first.

Comment: @vincebowdren No that was just a mistake in the response comments I wrote here which I couldn't seem to edit. Corrected here: //div[text() = ' Select this box']//input

Answer (score 0):

Your code works (tested with XpathpatherizerNPP):

```
//input[contains(text(),"Select this box")]
```